# Need help with hashMap with expiry time constraints

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, dictionary

I need a thread-safe Map with a time limited expiry policy. I tried looking for an existing library, but could not find one. Jboss cache is going to be a heavy alternative for my requirement. I have a first cut draft in place. Please have a look at the code posted on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ktx9WrEW)

I need constructive comments and enhancement suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) MapMaker:
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html

It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks, I forgot about guava.

Answer (score 1):

i'm sure ehcache would have something that would work.  maybe a bit "lighter" than jboss cache.